# Optimal sinusoidal Erathostenes' Sieve

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, integers, distribution-of-primes

NOTE: I have simplified this post [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2932654/559615). Please, consider reading that post instead of this one. Thanks.

Given the series of prime numbers greater than 9, we can organize them in four rows, according to their last digit ($d=1,3,7$ or $9$), and in $k=1,2,3\ldots$ columns corresponding to the $k$-multiple of $10$ we have to add to those four digits in order to obtain a prime number. Therefore, each prime is identified by a point $P(k,d)$.

I illustrate this representation in the following scheme.

[image]

For instance, in correspondence of the column $k=15$ ($x$-axis), we find two points in the rows $d=1$ and $d=7$ ($y$-axis), because $15\cdot 10+1=151$ and $15\cdot 10+7=157$ are primes.

Within this reference system, we can introduce the function

$$
f_1(k)=5+4\cos(\frac{\pi}{3}(k-1)),
$$

which pass through some of the points representing the primes (green).

[image]

Similarly, we can introduce the function

$$
f_2(k)=5+4\cos(\frac{\pi}{3}(k-2)),
$$

which pass (blue) through some *other* primes, with respect to the ones related to $f_1$:

[image]

Conversely, the (orange) function

$$
f_3(k)=5+4\cos(\frac{\pi}{3}(k-3)),
$$

[image]

pass through *some* primes related to the green function $f_2$ (in correspondence of $d=3$).

However, by means of $6$ functions in the form $f_h(k)=5+4\cos(\frac{\pi}{3}(k-h))$, with $h=1,2,3,4,5,6$  we are able to intercept all the primes:

[image]

My question rises from the fact that there is a sort of "multiplicity" of some primes, since they are reached by more than one function. Hence,

> Can we reduce the number of these functions, in such a way that each prime is intercepted by one and only one (sinusoidal) function?

Thanks for your comments and suggestions. I apologize in case of naivety/incorrectness.

EDIT: Thanks to the answer of Yves, I realized that the question might be not clear. Therefore, please, see also my own [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2931310/559615) for further clarifications.

Answer (score 3):

These sinusoids cover all integers ending in $1,3,7$ or $9$ ($1$ and $9$ once and $3$, $7$ twice). You are investigating the odd integers non-multiple of $5$, not the primes.

This plot of primes is aperiodic and the answer to your question is no.

Comment: IMO, you want to see a pattern where there is none.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! However, my question is not related to find patterns, but if we can find less than $6$ sinusoids covering all the integers ending in $1,3,7,9$ (and therefore all the primes) only once.

Comment: I posted another plot as an answer, maybe it was not clear what I was looking for. Sorry for that. Please, have a look and tell me your view. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Note, for example, that the period of $u_4(k)=5+2\cos \dfrac{\pi}{3}(k-4)$ is $6$ and that $u_4(4)=7$. That means that $u_4$ covers the arithmetic sequence $t_n = 6n + 7$. Dirichlet's theorem states that this sequence includes an infinite number of primes. Find another sine or cosine waves that covers the sequence of the form $6n+5$ and you will have included all primes except for $2$ and $3$.

Comment: Thanks Steven! Ok, very good hint. I didn't know this theorem. Do you think that we can reduce the number of waves and still remove the multiplicity (i.e. in such a way that each prime is intercepted by only one wave)?

Comment: The reason of this request lies in the fact that, in each ten, there are $0, 1, 2, 3$ or $4$  primes. Therefore, I somehow expect $5$ functions, not $6$.

Comment: you mean 6n ± 1 ?

Comment: @AdamWhite - Sure. I just liked that $6n+7$ is a prime number when $n=0$.