# Targeting all prime numbers with a minimal set of sinusoidal functions

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-factorization, distribution-of-primes

Given the series of prime numbers greater than 9, we can organize them in four rows, according to their last digit ($d=1,3,7$ or $9$), and in $k=1,2,3\ldots$ columns corresponding to the $k$-multiple of $10$ we have to add to those four digits in order to obtain a prime number. Therefore, each prime is identified by a single point $P(k,d)$.

I illustrate this representation in the following scheme.

[image]

For instance, in correspondence of the column $k=15$ ($x$-axis), we find two points on the rows $d=1$ and $d=7$ ($y$-axis), because $15\cdot 10+1=151$ and $15\cdot 10+7=157$ are primes.

Within this representation of prime numbers, we can introduce $6$ sinusoidal functions of $k$ such that each prime is intercepted by *one and only one* of these $6$ functions:

[image]

These $6$ sinusoidal functions are:

$$
\color{green}{ f_0(k)}=5+4\cos(\frac{\pi (k -0)}{3}),\,\,\,
\color{blue}{ f_1(k)}=5+4\cos(\frac{\pi (k-1)}{3}),
$$
$$
\color{orange}{ g_3(k)}=5+8\cos(\frac{\pi (k-3) }{3}),\,\,\,
\color{purple}{ g_4(k)}=5+8\cos(\frac{\pi (k-4)}{3}),
$$
$$
\color{brown}{ u_3(k)}=5+2\cos(\frac{\pi (k-3) }{3}),\,\,\,
\color{grey}{ u_4(k)}=5+2\cos(\frac{\pi (k-4)}{3}).
$$

We can underline the association between primes and functions by coloring the primes according to the (unique) function that pass through them, as shown in these pictures:

[image]

[image]

My question is:

> **Can we reduce the number of these sinusoidal functions and still attain the property that each prime is reached by one and only one function?**

The question is motivated by the fact that each ten (i.e. each $k$-multiple of $10$) can give rise to $0,1,2,3$ or $4$ primes, and therefore I somehow suspect that $5$ sinusoidal functions should be enough.

Thank you for your help and suggestions! Sorry for imprecision and trivialities.

NOTE: This post is a wrap of [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2931236/559615), in which the question was  unclear.

FINAL NOTE: The answer to this question is YES (thanks to user Empy2):

Four sinusoidal functions are  enough to target all prime numbers only once (i.e. each prime number is reached by one and only one wave). The four functions are
$$
f_{\pm}(k)=6\pm 2\sqrt{3}\cos\left[\frac{\pi}{3}\left(k−\frac{3}{2}\right) \right],
$$

$$
g_{\pm}(k)=4\pm 2\sqrt{3}\cos\left[\frac{\pi}{3}\left(k−\frac{1}{2}\right) \right].
$$

We can represent these $4$ functions as follows:

[image]

Comment: Are you saying that these functions take on all prime number values, in a unique manner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are sine-waves going through $$19,29,36,43,53,66,79,89,...\\
13, 23, 36,49,59,66,73,83,...\\
17,24,31,41,54,67,77,84,...\\
11,24,37,47,54,61,71,84,...$$

Comment: Thanks. But I didn't get your point. Do you mean that we can use only $4$ waves to target all the primes, each prime being targeted by only one of these four waves?

Comment: Exactly.  Multiples of 6 appear twice, and odd multiples of 3 don't appear at all.

Comment: Looks great! Please, can you help me to explicit these $4$ waves as a function of $k$?

Comment: $6\pn2\sqrt3\cos((x-1,5)\pi/3)$ and $4\pm2\sqrt3\cos((x-0.5)\pi/3)$, I think.

Comment: Yes! Great! Thank you so much Empy!

Comment: Very beautiful. I guess the number of waves cannot reduced further. But why?

Comment: Sometimes all four are needed, like 101,103,107,109

Comment: Sure. Really, really elegant. If you are interested in votes, please give your answer also here https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2931236/559615 and I will accept it. Thanks again for your neat explanations!

Comment: May I add the plot of your waves in your Answer?